# How to run Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership as a synchronous command?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a script that gets a user info from the AD. After the employee ID was provided the script gets all the user's groups and prints it as a list. After that it gets more attributes such as SamAccountName, LockedOut etc. Then it checks if the user is member of an "eTips" group.

My problem is that for some reason the output of the scripts shows not in the order that the scripts is written.

This is the code:

```
$EmpID = Read-Host "Enter Employee ID"
$ShowMemberOf = Read-Host "Want to see all the groups he members of (takes time...)? (y/n)"

if ($ShowMemberOf -eq "y" -or $ShowMemberOf -eq "yes") {
    $User = get-aduser -Filter {EmployeeID -like $EmpID} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    Write-Host "Group list:"
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | select name

    Write-Host "The rest of the user's info:"
    get-aduser -Filter {EmployeeID -like $EmpID} -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, PasswordExpired,
    PasswordLastSet, OfficePhone, LockedOut, Enabled, CN

    $MemberOfEtips = get-aduser -Filter {EmployeeID -like $EmpID} -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Select-String -Pattern "etips"
    if ($?) {
        write-host "Member of an eTips group"
    } 
    else {
        write-host "NOT member of eTips group"
    }

}

else {

    Write-Host "The rest of the user's info:"
    get-aduser -Filter {EmployeeID -like $EmpID} -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, PasswordExpired,
    PasswordLastSet, OfficePhone, LockedOut, Enabled, CN

    $MemberOfEtips = get-aduser -Filter {EmployeeID -like $EmpID} -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Select-String -Pattern "etips"
    if ($?) {
        "Member of an eTips group"
    } 
    else {
        "NOT member of eTips group"
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter Employee ID: 4449871
Want to see all the groups he members of (takes time...)? (y/n): y
Group list:

The rest of the user's info:

name                                 
----                                 
Domain Users                         
SMS_USERS                                                                   
dg_computingl            
ManagerUsers
eTips                    

Member of an eTips group
```

As you can see the script continues to run even though the "Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership" cmdlet wasn't complete yet. So the result is I'm getting the group list under the rest of 'the rest of the user's info' instead of under the 'Group list:'.

The second weird this is that because of that, it even doesn't run this part:

```
get-aduser -Filter {EmployeeID -like $EmpID} -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, PasswordExpired,
PasswordLastSet, OfficePhone, LockedOut, Enabled, CN
```

It just skips to the part where it checks of the user is part of eTips group.

Please explain what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `Write-Host` everywhere you used it, the other commands you use behave like `Write-Output`, this is why the order looks weird. Just put the strings you want to output on a line of their own, to have the same behavior and appropriate display.
2. The second `Get-ADUser` command does run, but I guess it simply does not produce any output, you should check it separately.
3. I'd rather run the `if` against `$MemberOfEtips` than `$?`, but that may only be a pattern unknown to me.
4. By default, a majority of PowerShell cmdlets are synchronous (there are specific exceptions, like jobs).

Comment: First of all, thank you! removing the `Write-Host` solved it.

Comment: 1. First of all, thank you! removing the `Write-Host` solved it.
2. Now it runs and shows the output (before that if I ran it separately it showed an output).
3. the `$?` holds the last output and checks if it's true (I used it after reading about in others' questions). I used it because I when I tried `if($MemberOfEtips -eq $true)` it didn't work. I guess it's because the value of  `$MemberOfEtips` is not Boolean.
4. Tnx for clearing that out :)

Comment: @HirNason I was thinking `if($MemberOfEtips) { #... }` :)

Comment: Your method works. so no need for the `-eq $true`, good to know that. Thank you again!